# how to use @MetaDataKeyParam in the @Source method in Anypoint-Devkit

Tags: mule, mule-component

I am developing a custom connector for generating Mule events.

So I am using the `@Source` annotation above the method.

I need to retrieve some metadata, and I also need to use the metadata keys as input during runtime. I have the following method signature with the mentioned annotations:

```java
@Source(sourceStrategy = SourceStrategy.POLLING, pollingPeriod = 5000)
public void getMessage(SourceCallback callback, @MetaDataKeyParam(affects = 
MetaDataKeyParamAffectsType.OUTPUT) String eventType,, int count)
```

Is there a way to implement dynamic metadata retrieval for `@Source` type i.e for callable module or event generator?